# How to get path in rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've seen calls to functions like

```
edit_person_path(person)
results_poll_path(poll)
```

But I can't replicate that to a path I've added

routes.rb

```
match 'proposals/:id/forkIt', :to => 'proposals#forkIt
```

And have `forkIt_proposal_path(proposal)`

So, i wanted to know, how do I achieve that.

P.S.: I'm noob to Ruby, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't set the route name. This should do the trick:

```
match 'proposals/:id/forkIt', :to => 'proposals#forkIt', :as => 'forkIt_proposal'
```

Or slightly more succinct:

```
match 'proposals/:id/forkIt' => 'proposals#forkIt', :as => 'forkIt_proposal'
```

Comment: Don't forget to also use the , :via => [:get] to limit the verbs that you expect (may not want a :delete call on this route)

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions (section 2.9 "adding more restful actions".)

not sure of what i say (im a noob too) but i think that path helpers are only created when you declare restful routes with resources() (in your case, add an action on member)

Edit: actually, the guide do state that path helpers are created doing this.